# How do I fix this problem and change it into a vector?

Tags: r

```r
players_syracuse <- filter(players_stats, names, college == "Syracuse University")
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input must be a vector, not a primitive function.
i Input `..1` is `names`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> View(players_syracuse)
Error in View : object 'players_syracuse' not found
```

I am using RStudio and I am trying to filter out data where I only show the players who went to that college. But it gave me a error. Do I have to use a different function or did I make a mistake? Im new thanks

Comment: Does `players_syracuse <- filter(players_stats, college == "Syracuse University") %>% select(names)` give you what you want?

Comment: Are you getting error with `dplyr::filter(iris, Species == 'setosa')`

Comment: That error (input `..1`) seems reminiscent of when `stats::filter` is being called with `dplyr::filter` in mind.